# How can get the value of the selected cell from a table created by php?

Tags: php, mysql

After I printed those values by using `PHP`, I got confused how to get the value of a selected cell.

```
<div>
    <php
       $query = mysql_query(select * from items, $conn);
       echo "<table border='1'>
             <th width ='120'>itemID</th>
             <th width ='120'>itemName</th>";
       while(row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
       {
          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>".$row['itemID']."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$row['itemName']."</td>";
       }
       echo "</table>";
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Please make your question clear

Comment: You want select value of what? and where you want it? on same page, other page. Please make sure your question will be clear to understand?

Comment: For example, i want to select the itemName and then print out in the same page the selected itemName

Answer (score 0):

seems you doing fine, iv'e just edited some typos, added tags,and changed to: "mysql_fetch_assoc" function. try this:

```
<div>
<?php
    $query = mysql_query("select * from items", $conn);
    echo "<table border='1'>
             <tr>
                 <th width ='120'>itemID</th>
                 <th width ='120'>itemName</th>
             </tr>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
         echo "<tr>";
         echo "<td>".$row['itemID']."</td>";
         echo "<td>".$row['itemName']."</td>";
         echo "</tr>";
     }
     echo "</table>";
?>
</div>
```